# How to make input bar's height dependent on amount of text

Tags: html, css, input

Here is my input bar's html:

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <input type="text" name="caption" class="btn btn-default outline input" autofocus/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default outline">
</div>
```

I want to let the bar increase it's row when the text is filled instead of keeping one line and letting it run on. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Edit:
In my html I have this php code:

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
if (!empty($_POST["caption"]) && !empty($_FILES["photo"]["name"]))
```

Therefore I need the textarea to have the id "caption" how do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried exploring textarea?

But it doesn't dynamically generate more rows for you thou. I'm no CSS expert but I'm pretty sure with some javascript u should be able to achieve it but that might be an overkill.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do a multiline input you will need to use a textarea element, but they have no ability to auto-grow on their own. You can use something like this https://github.com/ultimatedelman/autogrow though which is very easy to use e.g.

```
$('textarea').autogrow();
```

Edit:

Check to see if you're using jQuery already, if you're not put this at the bottom of your page before the closing body tag, if you're using a HTML5 doctype you can remove type="text/javascript".

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/autogrow"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('textarea').autogrow();
});
</script>
```

If you are already using jQuery somewhere, just make sure the last script tag is included after it.

Edit 2:

https://jsfiddle.net/k1cwaomo/

Comment: You'll need to use jQuery for this particular example, I'll add some code to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

rather than,

```
<input type="text">
```

You can add rows="" attribute to the  tag to assign the number of rows need to show

```
<textarea rows="5"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the id problem. Just write:

```
<textarea name="caption"></textarea>
```